# xlsxwriter Добавить запись в существующий лист

Tags: python-3.x

Пишу на python3.4
xlsxwriter 0.9.3

```
and@and-MS-1738 ~ $ uname -a
Linux and-MS-1738 3.16.0-38-generic #52~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 8 09:43:57 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Программа:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import xlsxwriter, os
file = 'data.xlsx'
path = os.getenv("PWD", os.getcwd())
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook(path + '/' + file)
ws = wb.get_worksheet_by_name("Поколение")
print("Листы:", wb.worksheets())
ws.write(0, 0, "123456")

wb.close()
```

при запуске получаю:

```
Листы: []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "тест2.py", line 8, in <module>
    ws.write(0, 0, "123456")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

В текущем каталоге точно есть файл data.xlsx и в нём точто есть лист "Поколение"
Причём добавить лист с помощью метода add_worksheet могу без проблем и далее писать в него, а вот получить объект существующего листа - ни в какую.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Посмотрите, будет ли проблема повторяться, если название листа будет состоять только из латинских букв.

Comment: Да, если название листа из латинских букв, проблема повторяется.